# Typescript Intellisense not working in even VS code even after adding type definition files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I started a project to understand how externally loaded types work with Typescript programming. So I started with a ts file which imports JsSHA and following is the code that I use to test the working of this library.

```
import * as jsSHA from "jssha";

class sha{
    shaObj: any;
    hash : string;

    constructor(){
        this.shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512","TEXT");
        this.shaObj.update("This is a test object");
        this.hash = this.shaObj.getHash("HEX");
    }
}

var s:sha = new sha();
console.log(s.hash);
```

In addition to adding JsSha.js via npm I also added the type definitions (.d.ts) of this library based on what is said [here](https://github.com/retyped/jssha-tsd-ambient). Despite doing all this I still don't get any intellisense related to JsSha object or the constructor method of this library. Am I missing something here that I should do in order to get things work.

PS: I restarted VS Code, Just in case to avoid any issues due to caching. Also updated all the existing packages that have any updates.

I'm using TS at 2.1.6, here are my dependencies and devdependencies from my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jssha": "^2.2.0",
  "retyped-jssha-tsd-ambient": "0.0.0-0",
  "typescript": "^2.1.6",
  "typings": "^2.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "retyped-jssha-tsd-ambient": "0.0.0-0"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "typings install dt~jssha" ?

Comment: You have the declarations installed twice in package.json which is certainly a potential issue. Furthermore, as it appears you're using typings, if you've installed the package with typings as well that is likely to conflict with the version(s) installed by in npm. The package.json file in the repo has neither a `"main"`entry point property nor a `"typings"` property. The lack of these properties, combined with the fact that the repository is not named after the module and that the declarations file is not named `"index"` will likely prevent it from being discovered automatically by TypeScript

Comment: I'll add to the declaration file itself very old and does not follow modern practices (it pollutes the global namespace unconditionally). Any reason not to just run `npm install --save @types/jssha`?

Answer (score 1):

The following set up provides intellisense on my machine. It fetches the declaration files from NPM, which is [the future of declaration files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jssha": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jssha": "0.0.29"
  }
}
```

[image: Demonstration of the jsSHA intellisense working.]